# SYMFONY3 in prod look for TWIG template in wrong folder instead of custom bundle indicated in routing.yml and AppKernel.php

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.7, symfony-3.1, symfony-3.2

I am implementing a SYMFONY 3 project in production mode for the first time.

I follow [OceanDigital](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-application-to-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial and the [standard doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html).

I went thru a bunch of issues linked to user writing rights that I've solved, and I do get now a SYMFONY ERROR page (one step closer to victory) with this message:

> Unable to find template "MyBundle:std_page:home.html.twig" (looked
>   into: /[folder to symf project]/app/Resources/views,
>   /[folder to symf project]/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form,
>   /[folder to symf project]/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views).

If I look in my [my symf project]\app\config\routing.yml, I have:

```
my_bundle:
  resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  options:
      expose: true
```

In [my symf project]\app\AppKernel.php, in the `registerBundles()` function, I have:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            ....
             new MyBundle\MyBundle(),
           .....
         ]
    }
}
```

And the file regarding the template that should be fetched `[my symf project]\src\MyBundle\Ressources\views/std_page/home.html.twig`  exists.

**What did I not set up right, in production mode, to have it looking for the TWIG template in the folder `[my symf project]\src\MyBundle\Ressources\views/`?**

Comment: You have to configure or add the folder to `Twig`,`$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array($templateDir1, $templateDir2));` or `$loader->addPath([my symf project]\src\MyBundle\Ressources\views);`

Comment: Change "MyBundle:std_page:home.html.twig" to "@MyBundle/std_page/home.html.twig" in your controller.

Comment: @DarkBee in which file (and folder) of the symfony project this line  is supposed to be?

Comment: @AndrzejPiszczek thanks for your input but your solution leads to change everything with no guarantee it will work at the end (I mean by that I get different error messages). Moreover SYMFONY best practices states that the TWIG template name pattern in a bundle should use colon (cf: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle). I prefer to not drift away from those recommendations.

Comment: Looks like you do it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050384/define-custom-filesystem-path-for-twig-templates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some search it happens to be a mistake similar to the one described in that [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299440/symfony-2-production-app-unable-to-find-any-twig-template).

In my controller I had:

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:Std_page:home.html.twig',$parameters);
```

Instead of:

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:std_page:home.html.twig',$parameters);
```

The development was made on a WINDOWS 10 OS, and it is set up in production on a UBUNTU 16.04. **It seems that UBUNTU is stricter than WINDOWS regarding the letter case.**